# Print a multiplication table with minimal code

Tags: r, seq, rbind

In R, what is the fastest way(shortest code) to print multiplication table?
The functions seq rep and the bind functions help, but I'm looking for the shortest line(s) of code to do this.

```
rbind("1\'s"=1:12, "2\'s"=seq(2,24,2), "3\'s"=seq(3,36,3), 
      "4\'s"=seq(4,48,4), "5\'s"=seq(5,60,5), "6\'s"=seq(6,72,6))
```

Prints the 1's through 6's going across (horizontally). Anyone know how to perform this in a more compact way?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
tbl <- outer(1:6, 1:12, "*")
rownames(tbl) <- paste(1:6, "'s", sep="")
tbl
```

You could make slightly more compact by using `paste0(1:6, "'s")`

This seems a slight improvement:

```
> v<-setNames(1:6, paste0(1:6, "\'s"))
> v %o% v
    1's 2's 3's 4's 5's 6's
1's   1   2   3   4   5   6
2's   2   4   6   8  10  12
3's   3   6   9  12  15  18
4's   4   8  12  16  20  24
5's   5  10  15  20  25  30
6's   6  12  18  24  30  36
```

Comment: Lightning fast (to enter). Thanks.

Comment: A few characters shorter still: `v <- 1:6; (tbl <- outer(setNames(v,paste0(v,"'s")),1:12))`

Answer (score 5):

A shortcut for `outer(1:6, 1:12, "*")`:

```
> 1:6 %o% 1:12
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10    11    12
[2,]    2    4    6    8   10   12   14   16   18    20    22    24
[3,]    3    6    9   12   15   18   21   24   27    30    33    36
[4,]    4    8   12   16   20   24   28   32   36    40    44    48
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25   30   35   40   45    50    55    60
[6,]    6   12   18   24   30   36   42   48   54    60    66    72
```