# Multiplication Table in R

Tags: r

I need to write a function that will print a multiplication table (for 1 to 10) to the console, given an integer specified by the user. The function should not have any parameters but should request input from the user.

Comment: Here's [similar question/possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840779/print-a-multiplication-table-with-minimal-code), you just need to solve user input part now.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function `mult_tab` that creates a multiplication table given an integer input by the user.

```
mult_tab <- function(n) seq.int(n) %o% seq.int(n)
```

For example,

```
mult_tab(4)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    2    3    4
# [2,]    2    4    6    8
# [3,]    3    6    9   12
# [4,]    4    8   12   16
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit of a tutorial on how to obtain user input and use it in a function [here](http://www.rexamples.com/4/Reading%20user%20input):

```
readinteger <- function()
{ 
  n <- readline(prompt="Enter an integer: ")
  return(as.integer(n))
}

print(readinteger())
```

There is a full tutorial on what you wish to achieve [here](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/examples/multiplication-table).

The code is as follows (clearly not mine as I have borrowed it from the above):

```
# R Program to find the multiplicationtable (from 1 to 10)
# take input from the user
num = as.integer(readline(prompt = "Enter a number: "))
# use for loop to iterate 10 times
for(i in 1:10) {
print(paste(num,'x', i, '=', num*i))
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
Enter a number: 7
[1] "7 x 1 = 7"
[1] "7 x 2 = 14"
[1] "7 x 3 = 21"
[1] "7 x 4 = 28"
[1] "7 x 5 = 35"
[1] "7 x 6 = 42"
[1] "7 x 7 = 49"
[1] "7 x 8 = 56"
[1] "7 x 9 = 63"
[1] "7 x 10 = 70"
```

Possibly a little bit of Google would have answered your question?

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted? The tutorial gives the code required and an explanation to go with it.

Comment: Hi Hester. I'm sure your intentions are good, but answers that only link somewhere else are typically discouraged. This is because links aren't stable and will likely die in the future, making this answer no longer valuable. One of the main goals of SO is to build a long-term repository of answers.

Comment: That's fine, I will post code.

Comment: Much better. The downvote was mine, I have retracted it.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
multiplication <- function(){

  m <- as.numeric(readline("Input: ")) # Take user input
  print(paste("Multiplication table of", m))
  # print multiplication table
  for (i in 1:10){ print (paste(m, "x", i, "=", i*m)) }  
}

multiplication()
```

Output:

```
Input: 7
#[1] "Multiplication table of 7"
#[1] "7 x 1 = 7"
#[1] "7 x 2 = 14"
#[1] "7 x 3 = 21"
#[1] "7 x 4 = 28"
#[1] "7 x 5 = 35"
#[1] "7 x 6 = 42"
#[1] "7 x 7 = 49"
#[1] "7 x 8 = 56"
#[1] "7 x 9 = 63"
#[1] "7 x 10 = 70"
>
```

Comment: How could one add text to the top of your results?

Comment: If you mean like a heading, just add a `print` statement before your `for` loop begins. Updated the code above with a heading at the top of the result.